# Get id in a page and search information ( ionic + angular )

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

By the method ui- sref I am sending an ID obtained from an array of scope , but would like to know how do I get that id in the page that I 'm sending ?

If I get the id , how do I look at the scope array of information regarding that id ?

```
<ion-view title="Noticias">
    <ion-content ng-controller="noticiasCtrl" style="top:0">
          <div class="header-image"></div>
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="item in rawData" class="item-noticias overlay" ng-style="{'background':'url(img/{{item.bg}}) no-repeat center', 'background-size':'cover'}">                
                <div class="overlay" ui-sref="forgotpassword({ id: item.tipo })">       
                    <p>{{ item.tipo }}</p>
                    <p>{{ item.titulo }}</p>
                    <p><a href="#/app/forgot-password">Leer mas</a></p>

                </div>                        
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>         
      </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controller :

```
.controller("noticiasCtrl", function($scope)
{

    $scope.rawData = [{
      "tipo": "noticia",
      "titulo": "Fin de semana de Madres",
      "bg": "img1.png"
    }, {
      "tipo": "evento",
      "titulo": "Eminem en vivo, 10% off",
      "bg": "img2.png"
    }, {
      "id": "noticia",
      "titulo": "12 Cosas para comprar",
      "bg": "img3.png"    
    }];
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get that `id` inside you controller using `$state`/`$stateParams` service. `$state.params.id` for `$state` & `$stateParams.id` for `$stateParams`.
Make sure you should injected the respective dependency before using it.

Additionally you shouldn't be using `{{}}` interpolation directive. Change your `ng-style` expression to `ng-style="{'background':'url(img/'+item.bg +') no-repeat center', 'background-size':'cover'}"`.

**Markup**

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in rawData| filter: {id: id}: true" class="item-noticias overlay" 
    ng-style="{'background':'url(img/'+item.bg +') no-repeat center', 'background-size':'cover'}">
    <div class="overlay" ui-sref="forgotpassword({ id: item.tipo })">
        <p>{{ item.tipo }}</p>
        <p>{{ item.titulo }}</p>
        <p><a href="#/app/forgot-password">Leer mas</a></p>
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

**Controller**

```
.controller("noticiasCtrl", function($scope, $state)
{
    //id retrieved from state, it could be different if variable name in state is different
    $scope.id = $state.params.id;
    $scope.rawData = [{
      "tipo": "noticia",
      "titulo": "Fin de semana de Madres",
      "bg": "img1.png"
    }, {
      "tipo": "evento",
      "titulo": "Eminem en vivo, 10% off",
      "bg": "img2.png"
    }, {
      "id": "noticia",
      "titulo": "12 Cosas para comprar",
      "bg": "img3.png"    
    }];
})
```

Comment: ok thank, but how show the get id sent in the new page, or how I access in the new page to scope for the data according to the id ?

Comment: @user3810167 inside new page controller you could easily access the parameter from URL using `$state`/`$stateParams`

Answer (score 0):

What is your `forgotpassword` function doing? That would be the thing that could generate the proper state ULR so that it could be extracted via `$state.params` on the route it lands on.